# Silverstripe Dropdown with Custom Objects

Tags: php, html, silverstripe

I have a custom DataObject called X. In this Dataobject amoung other fields, I want to have a DropdownField of other entries of custom DataObject Y. What I was exactly in that dropdown is the value -> url  and display title in dropdown to be the title. I can get the titles to appear in Dropdown but after looking with the inspector at the html looks like the **value attributes is always empty**.

```
class X extends DataObject {
    public static $db = array(
        'Title'  => 'Varchar(255)',
        'SortID' => 'Int'
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
        'Y' => 'Y',
        'Thumbnail' => 'Image'
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'ID', 'Title'
    );


    public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Title'),
            DropdownField::create(
                'Y',
                'Y',
                 Y::get()->map(array('URL' => 'Title'))
            ),
            UploadField::create('Thumbnail', 'Thumbnail')
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` methods accepts two arguments, the id of the array and the value.

```
DropdownField::create(
    'Y',
    'Y',
     Y::get()->map('URL', 'Title')
)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for you reply, now it seems to insert the right value, but displaying it in the template seems to return a server error. The problem occurs only for the value of the Dropdown, other field work so it's not a problem with the function I loop over. I tried accesing it with the following variable $Y

Comment: No more need, figured it out, your answer was very helpful. Thank you !